# Extracting numbers from a string under certain conditions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some strings that are stored in a dataframe using pandas and I want to extract all numbers out of them if it exists. The conditions these numbers must meet are quite specific and I'm not really sure if I can use regex to solve my problem. The conditions are:

- The number CANNOT be at the start of the string
- It CANNOT appear after the word "No. " or after the word "Question "

Also if possible, if the number has an e right after it I would want to keep that as well. However this is less important.

This is what I have so far to find all the numbers, but I do not know how to code the conditions I mentioned above.

```
testNumbers = re.findall(r'\d+', row['Name'])
```

For a given string: " Test T860 Article No. 9712250 787"

I would want the regex expression to return

```
[860, 787]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
(?!^)(?<!\d)(?<!\bNo\.\s)(?<!\bQuestion\s)(\d+)(?!\d)
```

In Python, declare as a raw string literal:

```
pattern = r'(?!^)(?<!\d)(?<!\bNo\.\s)(?<!\bQuestion\s)(\d+)(?!\d)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnKmud/2)

**Details**

- `(?!^)` - not at the start of the string
- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately before the current location is allowed
- `(?<!\bNo\.\s)` - no `No.` and a whitespace immediately before is allowed
- `(?<!\bQuestion\s)` - no `Question` and a whitespace immediately before is allowed
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately after the current location is allowed.

In Pandas, you may use it like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':[" Test T860 Article No. 9712250 787"," Test F199 Article Question 9712250787"]})
df['numbers'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'(?!^)(?<!\d)(?<!\bNo\.\s)(?<!\bQuestion\s)(\d+)(?!\d)').apply(','.join)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                     text  numbers
0       Test T860 Article No. 9712250 787  860,787
1   Test F199 Article Question 9712250787      199
```

Comment: Can you adjust this so it won't match a number at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Just `(?!^)` will do.

Comment: Small doubt. Is the order of the neg lookbehinds here irrelevant, as they al refer to `(\d+)`?

Comment: @yatu They are zero-width assertions. All of them are executed before `\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use an expression with word boundaries and quantifier:

```
\b[A-Z]+(\d+)\b|\b([0-9]{1,3})\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8t8Qyk/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired or you wish to modify it, please visit [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8t8Qyk/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]