# Searching for substrings in a string that match a certain condition

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This is sort of a continuation of my other post: [Extracting numbers from a string under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546141/extracting-numbers-from-a-string-under-certain-conditions)

To summarize, I have some strings that are stored in a dataframe and I want to extract the first number that matches all the conditions (if it exists). Here are the conditions:

- The number CANNOT be at the start of the string
- It CANNOT appear after the word "No. " or after the word "Question"
- The number CANNOT be between the values 1960 - 2020
- If the number is immediately followed by the letter e, I want to
  extract the e with it

This is what I have so far to find the numbers, it takes care of the first two conditions:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    test = re.search(r'(?!^)(?<!\bNo\.\s)(?<!\bQuestion\s)(\d+)(?!\d)',
                     row['name'])
    if test:
        df.loc[
            df['name'] == row['name'], ['id']] = test.group()
```

I've also tried using:

```
\b(?!196[0-9]\d|20[012][0])\d+\b
```

to account for the the number not being between the values of 1960 - and 2020, but it doesn't seem to work. I also don't understand how to catch the e if it's there.

Example 1:

```
"Trial No. 32819 Question 485 Article 787e"
```

I would want the regex expression to return

```
[787e]
```

Example 2:

```
"2981 XYZ Legislature"
```

I would want the regex expression to return

```
None
```

Example 3"

```
"Addendum217Null"
```

I would want the regex expression to return

```
[217]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You may try `r'(?!^)(?<!\bNo\.\s)(?<!\bQuestion\s)(?<!\d)(?!(?:19[6-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9]|2020)(?!\d))(\d+(?!\d)e?)'`

Comment: what about `'1975e'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
(?!^)(?<!\bNo\.\s)(?<!\bQuestion\s)(?<!\d)(?!(?:19[6-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9]|2020)(?!\d))(\d+(?!\d)e?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WP1N7L/1/)

The new part is `(?<!\d)(?!(?:19[6-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9]|2020)(?!\d))(\d+(?!\d)e?)`:

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?!(?:19[6-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9]|2020)(?!\d))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a number from `1960` to `2020` not followed with a digit
- `(\d+(?!\d)e?)` - Group 1 (what you will get extracted): 1+ digits that are not followed with a digit and an optional `e` letter